# Trying to consolidate pairs of accounting periods in a query that sums dollar amounts

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling with how to get a query to sum pairs of accounting periods as if they were one value instead of two. We basically have each period and it has a corresponding adjusting period (4 and 904 for example) and I want to sum those together since my query returns them as separate rows. I want 904 to essentially be considered 4 by the query. I need to do this for each period 1 through 12 (and 901 through 912) as I'm only interested in if there are differences from one month to another and not interested if there are differences between the period and adjustment period.

```
SELECT PROJECT_ID, ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, SUM(POSTED_BASE_AMT) as POSTED_AMT
FROM PS_LEDGER
WHERE LEDGER = 'ACTUALS'
AND FISCAL_YEAR = '2019'
AND (PROJECT_ID like 'PG%' OR PROJECT_ID LIKE 'GG%')
AND ACCOUNT BETWEEN '40000' AND '79999'
AND ACCOUNTING_PERIOD <> 999
GROUP BY PROJECT_ID, ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
HAVING SUM(POSTED_BASE_AMT) <> 0
ORDER BY PROJECT_ID, ACCOUNTING_PERIOD;
```

My results with this are like:

```
PROJECT_ID             ACCOUNTING PERIOD       POSTED_AMT
GG000000                       4                    -100
GG000000                      904                    100
```

And for the purposes of this query I'd like that to be 0

Comment: This is a good reference guide for asking SQL questions: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ In this case, if you provide some sample input data along with the expected result it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your adjustment period is always 901 through 912, you can just subtract 900 and the group by would combine it with the original period.

```
SELECT PROJECT_ID, 
CASE WHEN ACCOUNTING_PERIOD<900 THEN ACCOUNTING_PERIOD ELSE 900-ACCOUNTING_PERIOD END ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, 
SUM(POSTED_BASE_AMT) as POSTED_AMT
FROM PS_LEDGER
WHERE LEDGER = 'ACTUALS'
AND FISCAL_YEAR = '2019'
AND (PROJECT_ID like 'PG%' OR PROJECT_ID LIKE 'GG%')
AND ACCOUNT BETWEEN '40000' AND '79999'
AND ACCOUNTING_PERIOD <> 999
GROUP BY PROJECT_ID, CASE WHEN ACCOUNTING_PERIOD<900 THEN ACCOUNTING_PERIOD ELSE 900-ACCOUNTING_PERIOD END 
HAVING SUM(POSTED_BASE_AMT) <> 0
ORDER BY PROJECT_ID, CASE WHEN ACCOUNTING_PERIOD<900 THEN ACCOUNTING_PERIOD ELSE 900-ACCOUNTING_PERIOD END;
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I'll try these out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you want:

```
SELECT PROJECT_ID, 
       ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, 
       SUM(POSTED_BASE_AMT) OVER 
         ( PARTITION BY MOD(Accounting_Period,100)
         ) as POSTED_AMT
FROM PS_LEDGER
WHERE LEDGER = 'ACTUALS'
AND FISCAL_YEAR = '2019'
AND (PROJECT_ID like 'PG%' OR PROJECT_ID LIKE 'GG%')
AND ACCOUNT BETWEEN '40000' AND '79999'
AND ACCOUNTING_PERIOD <> 999;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions from Paul X really helped but I needed to run the query first and get the posted base amounts not summed, and then have that in a nested select in the query like this:

SELECT PROJECT_ID, ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, SUM(POSTED_BASE_AMT) as AMOUNT
FROM (SELECT PROJECT_ID, 
CASE WHEN ACCOUNTING_PERIOD >900 THEN ACCOUNTING_PERIOD - 900 ELSE ACCOUNTING_PERIOD END ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, 
POSTED_BASE_AMT
FROM PS_LEDGER
WHERE LEDGER = 'ACTUALS'
AND FISCAL_YEAR = '2019'
AND (PROJECT_ID like 'PG%' OR PROJECT_ID LIKE 'GG%')
AND ACCOUNT BETWEEN '40000' AND '79999'
AND ACCOUNTING_PERIOD <> 999)
GROUP BY PROJECT_ID, ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
HAVING SUM(POSTED_BASE_AMT) <> 0
ORDER BY PROJECT_ID, ACCOUNTING_PERIOD;

thanks for all your help, everyone!!